# cannot access /dev/video*: No such file or directory

Tags: linux-kernel, usb, webcam, zynq

So I'm working on a zynq z7000 card and I made a Linux Kernel on it. I put a Linaro as a Root File System. I managed to boot the card however I can only use mouse and keyboard usb devices. I tried webcam and flash drives but they are not working. when I use :

```
lsusb
```

I get the webcam device

```
...
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 046d:0805 Logitech, Inc. Webcam C300
```

However when I try

```
ls /dev/video*
```

I get

```
ls: cannot access /dev/video*: No such file or directory
```

I've used [these configurations](https://github.com/analogdevicesinc/linux/blob/xcomm_zynq/arch/arm/configs/zynq_xcomm_adv7511_defconfig) to build my image.

Comment: There are probably dozens or hundreds of things that could be the problem. For starters, do you even have video support compiled into your kernel? This page may help, as it lists your camera: http://www.ideasonboard.org/uvc/

Comment: using these step you may get some help [link](http://www.ideasonboard.org/uvc/faq/#faq1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure if v4l2 framework and UVC Class driver are enabled in your kernel configuration(defconfig file). Or can enable using menuconfig. Make sure the following are there:
1. CONFIG_VIDEO_V4L2=y
2. CONFIG_VIDEO_V4L2_COMMON=y
3. CONFIG_VIDEO_DEV=y
4. CONFIG_USB_VIDEO_CLASS=y

Comment: I made sure they are enabled however system doesn't appear to be using any driver: when I try lsmod nothing is used!

Comment: with CONFIG_VIDEO_V4L2=y, the driver module wont be listed in lsmod. If it is made as CONFIG_VIDEO_V4L2=m and if the module is installed in the filesystem, the module needs to be insmoded and then it will appear in lsmod.