# webcam + external camera failure, cannot access /dev/video*: No such file or directory

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, uvc, video4linux

I hope someone out there can help me!

I'm working on a Toshiba SATELLITE-L50-A-1DN, and I am having problems connecting a camera to the USB ports, as well as the integrated webcam not being recognised.

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 with kernel 4.13.0-45-generic

After plugging in an external webcam, `lsusb` does not change, indicating no device has been recognised.

`ls -ltrh /dev/video*` returns the error: `ls: cannot access '/dev/video*': No such file or directory`

I have tried installing uvcvideo, but the most up to date version is already installed. Related to this, I cannot access the Video4Linux module required to use one of the two cameras I am trying to use.

I am aware of the same question being posted here: [cannot access /dev/video*: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36159501/cannot-access-dev-video-no-such-file-or-directory) but I can't seem to make that solution work for me.

Comment: your system upgraded or not??

Comment: What do you mean by this? I frequently run `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade`

Comment: Yaa you did it..

Answer (score 0):

> In dev is there root direct:

```
my@my-u18gv:~$ cd /dev/video0
```

> If the bellow msg come:

```
No such file or directory
```

> Then there may be two cases if i found and try to fix:

*
 1.) The ubuntu machine or linux machine.
*

> There may be various scenario or dependencies which may be causing
>   this but this what i check on both condition. The the packages and
>   retart the system

```
sudo apt-get update
```

> To check the webcamp you can use cheese or any other it depends on
>   you:

```
sudo apt-get install cheese
cheese
```

*
 2.) Ubuntu in Virtual Machine running on windows.
*
I'm using ubuntu 18.04, virtual machine 5.2.14 on windows 10 64bit.

Steps:

- Open the VM Virtual Box and select the snapshot you are using.
- Select the Settings
- Select the USB menu at the left
- Enable the usb controller and select the USB 2.0 (EHCI) cintroller
- Click from USB Device_filter there is a usb cable icon with '+' sign at the right side.
- Select your device from the list. In my list it was realtek semiconductor corp.

Here you may face one issue:
while selecting and USB 2.0 and when you start then if you get below error.

failed to install extension pack VERR_SYMBOL_NOT_FOUND ..

Then you need to install  VM VirtualBox Extension Pack.

Note: take care that the version of the VM virtualbox and extension package should be same or it might give you error.

Steps: For installing VM VirtualBox Extension Pack
link:https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Download_Old_Builds_5_2
For every version you will find the extension package you need in above link.

- Open the VM Virtual Box and click on File --> Preferences --> Extensions
- Click on Plus icon and Add the extension which you downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

Execute the command:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5cBhM.jpg)

system error:

[ERROR] [1575905480.653251919]: Unable to identify '/dev/video0': 2, No such file or directory
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kr0hy.jpg)

Answers:

First of all, try your own laptop camera good or bad (do a QQ search, etc...); no problem found

Then review the virtual machine settings. The blue circle has not been opened before and the virtual machine must be turned off for it to be marked;

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JeFDU.jpg)

Reboot, the camera device can now be found in the virtual machine and check "Connect (disconnect from host)".

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kB9od.jpg)

Re-run the command, the camera can open correctly

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Me63z.jpg)

I hope it works